# Try/Catch does not prevent crash

Tags: javascript, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am writing a very simple telegram-bot using the [telegraf bot framework](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf).
So far it replies to some simple commands using `.hears` and `.on` methods, everything works fine so far.

Now I implemented another `.hears` method which is waiting for the string `Miez`. Once it "hears" this string it is supposed to `.replyWithDocument` containing a [cat-api](http://thecatapi.com/) url. The URL according to cat-api provides a random cat-gif on every call. So far my code:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

const app = new Telegraf('<MY_TOKEN>')

// Connect/Express.js integration
const express = require('express')
const expressApp = express()

expressApp.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));


app.command('start', (ctx) => {
  console.log('start', ctx.from)
  ctx.reply('Welcome!')
})

app.hears('Hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hallo!'))
app.hears('Marco', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Polo'))
app.on('sticker', (ctx) => ctx.reply('❤'))

app.hears('Miez',(ctx) => {
    try{
          return ctx.replyWithDocument({
            url: 'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif',
            filename: 'cat.gif'
          })

       }catch(error){
            return ctx.reply("Miau");
       }
})
```

So as you can see I wraped the `.replyWithDocument` in a try/catch block. I did this because the given [url](http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif) does not always provide a gif. Sometimes you just get a `Server not found` message. I am hosting the bot on Heroku and here are the logs for the corresponding error:

```
Failed to process updates. { FetchError: request to http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lu65p0QXgW1r4xjo2o1_r1_500.gif failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 30.media.tumblr.com 30.media.tumblr.com:80
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/telegraf/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:133:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1022:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  message: 'request to http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lu65p0QXgW1r4xjo2o1_r1_500.gif failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 30.media.tumblr.com 30.media.tumblr.com:80',
  name: 'FetchError',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  type: 'system',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND' }
```

After this is thrown, the bot stops working on Heroku for a while and then comes back up again after 15 minutes or something, I guess it gets restarted after some time of inactivity.

Well, at the bottom line I do not mind the url-call to fail sometimes. What I do not understand is why my try/catch-block is not catching this behaviour. In case my interpretation of the logs is correct.

**Edit:** A possible reason came to my head, maybe `.replyWithDocument` is a asynchronous call. So the HTTP-request is successful and the try is too. But once the response is `Server not found` the method call still fails. If this might be the reason, how would one handle it?

Comment: If replyWithDocument is promise based, use .catch(). If it's callback based, handle the error parameter in the callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Telegraf custom error handling methods!.

> By default Telegraf will print all errors to stderr and rethrow error.
>   To perform custom error-handling logic use following snippet:

```
const app = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
app.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Ooops', err)
})
```

Try using above code to catch your 'ENOTFOUND' error.

Source: http://telegraf.js.org/introduction.html#error-handling